# wls2 has high number of defunct processes immediately after starting

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

when I start up WLS2 Ubuntu 20.04 and do `ps aux` I see a lot of *zombie processes*. I have cross checked with one of my coworkers and he doesn't have any defunct process listed.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0    896   584 ?        Sl   08:54   0:00 /init
root        44  0.0  0.0    896    84 ?        Ss   08:54   0:00 /init
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        47  0.0  0.0    896    84 ?        S    08:54   0:00 /init
root        48  0.0  0.2 1464440 35180 pts/1   Ssl+ 08:54   0:00 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy --distro-name Ubuntu-20.04 --docker-desktop-root /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        86  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        88  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root        90  0.0  0.0    896    84 ?        Ss   08:54   0:00 /init
root        91  0.0  0.0    896    84 ?        D    08:54   0:00 /init
blue        92  0.0  0.0  10768  5824 pts/0    Ss   08:54   0:00 -bash
root       100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root       141  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root       143  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root       146  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root       148  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root       150  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:54   0:00 [init] <defunct>
root       152  0.0  0.0    896    84 ?        S    08:54   0:00 /init
blue       153  0.0  0.3 765016 39988 pts/2    Ssl+ 08:54   0:00 docker serve --address unix:///home/blue/.docker/run/docker-cli-api.sock
blue       453  0.0  0.0  10620  3276 pts/0    R+   09:22   0:00 ps aux
```

I am not sure whats is the problem or how to fix it.

Comment: Just tried it on mine - This seems to be a new issue with Docker Desktop.  When I quit Docker Desktop, the defunct processes are gone.  Restart Docker Desktop - They are back.  I have another computer on which I haven't updated Docker Desktop, so it's at 3.3.0 -- It does *not* have this issue.  With 3.5.2, it happens with any WSL2 instance for which the Docker integration is enabled.

Comment: I was suspecting docker to be the cause since its the only thing that starts automatically in WLS when I turn on my laptop. Especially after the comments on SO regarding `/etc/init.d`. Thanks for cross checking and confirming. Do you think I should open an issue on docker-desktop?

Comment: Yes, I'd love it if you would open an issue there.  Please link it back here when you do - Thanks!

Comment: Here is the issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11907